# CloudKit Sharing

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am having trouble understanding some of the CloudKit sharing concepts and the WWDC 2016 "What's new in CloudKit" video doesn't appear to explain everything that is required to allow users to share and access shared records.

I have successfully created an app that allows the user to create and edit a record in their private database.
I have also been able to create a Share record and share this using the provided sharing UIController.  This can be successfully received and accepted by the participant user but I can't figure out how to query and display this shared record.

The app creates a "MainZone" in the users private database and then creates a CKRecord in this "MainZone".  I then create and save a CKShare record and use this to display the UICloudSharingController.

How do I query the sharedDatabase in order to access this record ?  I have tried using the same query as is used in the privateDatabase but get the following error:

```
"ShareDB can't be used to access local zone"
```

EDIT

I found the problem - I needed to process the accepted records in the AppDelegate.  Now they appear in the CloudKit dashboard but I am still unable to query them.  It seems I may need to fetch the sharedDatabase "MainZone" in order to query them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dude, I got it: First you need to get the *CKRecordZone* of that Shared Record. You do it by doing the following:

```
let sharedData = CKContainer.default().sharedCloudDatabase
    sharedData.fetchAllRecordZones { (recordZone, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let recordZones = recordZone {
            // Here you'll have an array of CKRecordZone that is in your SharedDB!
        }
    }
```

Now, with that array in hand, all you have to do is fetch normally:

```
func showData(id: CKRecordZoneID) {

    ctUsers = [CKRecord]()

    let sharedData = CKContainer.default().sharedCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Elder", predicate: predicate)

    sharedData.perform(query, inZoneWith: id) { results, error in
        if let error = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Cloud Query Error - Fetch Establishments: \(error)")
            }
            return
        }
        if let users = results {
            print(results)
            self.ctUsers = users
            print("\nHow many shares in cloud: \(self.ctUsers.count)\n")
            if self.ctUsers.count != 0 {
                // Here you'll your Shared CKRecords!
            }
            else {
                print("No shares in SharedDB\n")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this approach, what happens if there are millions of users sharing things ?  There will be millions of recordZones so this query could be very big.  I think the correct approach seems to be to store a local reference to things that are shared with your user and to use these to query changes.  I think the idea is also to minimise queries and rather register for changes and then process the changes - however I would be concerned that might also result in too much push traffic under some circumstances.

Comment: Mmm - actually you may be right as the user would only see the zones from records that are shared with them !

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand quite well **when** you want to get those informations. I'm with the same problem as you, but I only can get the shared data by clicking the URL... To do that you'll need two functions. First one in *AppDelegate*:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith cloudKitShareMetadata: CKShareMetadata) {

    let acceptSharesOperation = CKAcceptSharesOperation(shareMetadatas: [cloudKitShareMetadata])
    acceptSharesOperation.perShareCompletionBlock = {
        metadata, share, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            let viewController: ViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! ViewController
            viewController.fetchShare(cloudKitShareMetadata)
        }
    }
    CKContainer(identifier: cloudKitShareMetadata.containerIdentifier).add(acceptSharesOperation)
}
```

in *ViewConroller* you have the function that will fetch this MetaData:

```
func fetchShare(_ metadata: CKShareMetadata) {
    let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: [metadata.rootRecordID])
    operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = { record, _, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        if record != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.currentRecord = record
                //now you have your Shared Record
            }
        }
    }
    operation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { _, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    CKContainer.default().sharedCloudDatabase.add(operation)
}
```

As I said before, I'm now trying to fetch the ShareDB without accessing the URL. I don't want to depend on the link once I already accepted the share. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks this makes sense but how would I query all the shared records from the database or is the App expected to keep its own copies of these shared records (either locally or in the privateDatabase) ?  I don't want to store the data locally I just want to query the shared records but there seems to be no way to do that except by querying each shared zone.

Comment: Sadly, I'm in the same place as you, trying to figure it out this. The shared content doesn't stay in you privateDB, it stays in the sharedDB. What I tried to do was query like a normal CKRecord, after all, CKShare is a reference to CKRecord! But once I perform the query with the *ZoneID* I got the same message that you got "ShareDB can't be used to access local zone"

Comment: I check the records zoneID and query in the zoneID which works fine.  So I keep the private database zoneID and compare with the records zoneID and if they don't match then I know it must be a sharedDatabase query and then the zoneID is required in the query.  For now I will store a copy of all the Shared zoneID's in the privateDatabase to make it easy to know which zones to query in the sharedDatabase.

Comment: I understand now, this message "ShareDB can't be used to access local zone" was appearing because I was using the ZoneID of the privateDB, not the sharedDB!